# Check for perfect squares in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to identify numbers which are perfect squares in a list of numbers, for example:

```
a = [3, 4, 8, 16, 21, 58, 144]  # return [4, 16, 144]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once approach is to build a predicate (a function returning true or false) and apply it with [*filter()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter):

```
>>> def is_perfect_square(n):
        return round(n ** 0.5) ** 2 == n

>>> list(filter(is_perfect_square, [3, 4, 8, 16, 21, 58, 144]))
[4, 16, 144]
```

Or for those who prefer list comprehensions over *filter()*:

```
>>> [x for x in [3, 4, 8, 16, 21, 58, 144] if is_perfect_square(x)]
[4, 16, 144]
```

The perfect square test works by taking the square root of a number and rounding it to the nearest integer, re-squaring it and comparing it to a the original number.  The square root step can suffer a little round-off error, but the re-squaring of the rounded integer will be exact.  This should be somewhat robust except for very large inputs.

Answer (score 3):

You can combine `math.sqrt()` and `is_integer()` to filter the list, like the following:

```
import math

a = [3, 4, 8, 16, 21, 58, 144]
print [x for x in a if math.sqrt(x).is_integer()]
```

Comment: This is mathematically correct but I worry that it could be thrown-off by tiny round-off errors in the math.sqrt.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
>>> square_list = []
>>> a = [3, 4, 8, 16, 21, 58, 144]
>>> def perfect_square(number):
    return (number**0.5) % int(number**0.5) == 0

>>> for data in a:
    if perfect_square(data):
        square_list.append(data)


>>> print square_list
[4, 16, 144]
```

Answer (score -1):

Using this test for perfect squares:

```
def is_square(n):
    for b in range(n):
        n -= (2 * b + 1)
        if n <= 0:
            return not n
```

... you can find those that appear in `a` with a simple list comprehension:

```
>>> [n for n in a if is_square(n)]
[4, 16, 144]
```

Comment: perfect thanks.. @Zero Piraeus

Comment: That test for squares does *way* too much work.  You should be able to determine when a number is perfect square without looping over a large number of candidates.

Comment: Yeap this is point sir @RaymondHettinger but for every number how to check this.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger well ... yes. This was actually kinda tongue in cheek; it's obviously a homework assignment posted by someone who hasn't put the slightest effort in, so I impishly decided to go find an obscure perfect square test they could present and then be unable to explain. Now that it's accepted, I don't think I can delete it.

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus I commend your impishness and creativity :-)  Well played.